# If Launchd does not run today, run alternate command

Tags: macos, launchd

**Problem synopsis:**

- When my laptop is off at 11PM, launchd does not run the command `srd exec`.
- If Launchd runs the command when I get started the next day, it should run `srd exec -y` instead.

**Explanation:**

I have a Launchd configured with Lingon to run [Sifttter Redux](https://github.com/bachya/Sifttter-Redux) on my OSX 10.10 laptop at 11PM every day. Quite often, the laptop is off at that time, otherwise the command does run successfully with expected results. It will also run as expected on demand from Terminal.

Given that this application's purpose is essentially a logger, finding activity from specific date ranges in a text file and aggregating it into Day One entries for those days, the command should only be run once for every day or else duplicate entries are created.

When I input `srd exec`, today's information is found and added to today's entry. When I input `srd exec -y`, yesterday's info is found and added to yesterday's entries.

There are also parameters for date ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by creating a bash script which checks the time and executes `srd` with respective parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash

NOW=$(date +"%H")
echo $(date);
if [[ $NOW == 23 ]]
    then
        /usr/bin/srd exec --verbose
        echo "Sifttter grabbed today's events.";
else
    /usr/bin/srd exec -y --verbose
    echo "Sifttter caught up on yesterday's events.";
fi
```

The task ran properly when run directly from terminal, but when run through launchd the stdout showed it cutting off halfway through and the sifttter proper log is showed `invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII`.

This issue was fixed by adding the following character declaration to the launchd plist:

```
<key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
<dict>
  <key>LANG</key>
    <string>en_US.UTF-8</string>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try establishing a log file, and append the date to that file every time the agent successfully launches.  Create an 11:00 AM agent that checks the log, and if yesterday's date is not present, launch the `-y` version, and you are done.

Comment: I created a bash script which checks the time and executes `srd` with respective parameters. The task runs properly when run directly from terminal, but when run through launchd the stdout shows it cutting off halfway through and the `sifttter` proper log is showing `invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII` .

Comment: Found the fix in adding language specifications to my launchd plist per this issue: [Slogger issue 222](https://github.com/ttscoff/Slogger/issues/222).

Comment: Nice!  That beats the log file.